# Parse url like requets.Request.url which prepared

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm testing on some ajax requests.
I've prepared a login `session`, wanna `get` request

sample input:

> GET:
>   /ajax/uri
>   Params:
>   context:{JSON_STRING}

sample output:

> url/ajax/uri?context=_QUOTED_JSON_STRING

I can get the output in this way:

```
r = requests.Request(url='url/ajax/uri', method='get', params={'context':JSON_STRING})
url = r.prepare().url
# next step: session.get(url)
```

I wonder if there's a more elegant&simple way to do the thing for I only wanna the prepared url. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/

```
s.get('url/ajax/uri', params={'context':JSON_STRING})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the URL, you can encode the GET parameters with `urlencode`, your values can be JSON strings

```
>>> import urllib
>>> 'url/ajax/uri?%s' % urllib.urlencode({'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'})
'url/ajax/uri?key2=value2&key1=value1'
```